# How do I loop a list based on current day?

Tags: php, loops, date

I have a simple XML list with dates inside (chronological order). I have found a way loop the list 7 times (1 week).

```
<?php
    $xmldata=simplexml_load_file("dates.xml");
    $i = 0;
    foreach($xmldata->day as $day) {
    if($i==7) break;
    $i++;
    echo "<p>Date: " . $day->date . "</p>";
    echo "<p>Dayname: " . $day->content . "</p>";
    }
    ?>
```

Now I have the problem, that the loop always starts at the first line of the XML file and ends after 7 times. But I want to start the loop, when

```
 $xmldata->day->date = $currentday;
 $currentday = date('d.m.y');
```

and continue with the next 7 items (days) in the list.

The XML (dates.xml) looks like this:

```
<schedule>
  <day>
    <date>01.03.17</date>
    <information>Lorem ipsum</information>
  </day>
  <day>
    <date>02.03.17</date>
    <information>Lorem ipsum</information>
  </day>
  <day>
    <date>03.03.17</date>
    <information>Lorem ipsum</information>
  </day>
  ...
</schedule>
```

Thank you!

Comment: So add before `if($i==7) break;` this `if($day->date!=date('d.m.y')) continue;`

Comment: Ok cool. I did this. Now I get only the value from today. Which is pretty good, but the other 6 days in the loop are missing. It seems like `if($i==7) break;
$i++;` will be ignored.

Comment: ok, little mess, wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution after commnets:

```
<?php
$xmldata=simplexml_load_file("dates.xml");
$i = 0; 
$startfound = false;
foreach($xmldata->day as $day) {
    if(!$startfound && $day->date!=date('d.m.y')) continue;
    $startfound = true;
    if($i==7) break;
    $i++;
    echo "<p>Date: " . $day->date . "</p>";
    echo "<p>Dayname: " . $day->content . "</p>";
}
?>
```